# Notepad++ Regex replace white spaces and code

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, whitespace

Regex experts how to replace this.

```
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO fefwioef239nvxc3rlk32nrsdf SOME QUOTED INFO -->
<div>random div</div>
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO fkn3209vnsdlkvn09432ns SOME QUOTED INFO -->
```

How the replace with nothing(in order to delete it) all the

```
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO xxxxcodexxxx SOME QUOTED INFO -->
```

I have tried the following expression in the notepad seacher and click the regex radio button:

```
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO\s+*\s+SOME QUOTED INFO -->
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with empty string.

```
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO\s+\S+\s+SOME QUOTED INFO -->[\n\r]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW0mT4/4)

**OR**

```
<!-- SOME QUOTED INFO\h+\S+\h+SOME QUOTED INFO -->[\n\r]*
```

`\h+` matches one or more horizontal spaces and `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

Comment: Thanks! that was fast you are the winner!